# android app to control arduino using usb

Tags: usb

I am trying to figure out how i could make an android app like this one, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVj0jqOlGXo but instead of transmitting through bluetooth it would transmit it through a usb cable that plugs from my phone directly into my arduino.

Comment: There are no "good" answers for this, but two classes of possibilities - USB host mode, and "accessory" or "ADK" mode.  Both have a number of issues.  Both have received substantial coverage on the main stackoverflow site which you should read (**do not** simply post a new question there) and elsewhere online.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to look *USB Serial port communication in android*. Some googling will help
 here's a nice example of such work, described in detail:

http://felhr85.net/2015/01/09/a-dirty-and-quick-example-of-serial-port-communication-in-android/

And in case the codes/that source gets lost, here is the
GitHub link of the developer: https://github.com/felHR85/SerialPortExample